# How did the Aufbau principle come to be?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, history, orbitals, quantum-chemistry

How did the [Aufbau principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle) come to be? Being that my education on chemistry doesn't go past highschool, i was never sure how the following diagram was conceived:

[image]

I would like to understand how the 20th century physicists arrive at this sequence? What was the line of reasoning behind it? Was it derived empirically or is it achievable through the math in quantum mechanics?

Comment: Linus Pauling won the Chemistry nobel prize in 1954, and the peace nobel prize in 1962. I don't know either what "his diagram" or "his conclusion" refers to, though...

Comment: In my country (Brazil) it is called "Pauling diagrams" at schools and such, but in English it is usually called Aufbau principle/Madelung rule: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle#History

Comment: If you happen to speak portuguese, there's a nice video about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ebFzgQuX_0&t=70s

Comment: I'm also willing to bet some hard cash someone in Brazil once heard Pauli had something to do with it and mixed it up with Pauling and our school system has been damaged by this confusion ever since...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a better fit to [hsm.se].

Comment: See https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8930/ for the general guidelines on history questions. This is squarely on the side of histotical-interest questions that should go to [hsm.se] (after a suitable reworking to use standard terminology that can be understood internationally).

Comment: @Petrini by "Pauling diagram" the OP is referring to this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/594754 (you're right about "aufbau", see: https://edu.rsc.org/feature/the-trouble-with-the-aufbau-principle/2000133.article )

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103718/2451 and links therein.