# Why do groups in the periodic table have missing periods?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals

What is the reason for skipping groups in the periodic table?

To word this another way: why isn't the electron configuration of Vanadium defined as `1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p6 3d5` instead of `1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p6 3d3 4s2`?  What causes the jump to the fourth group instead of filling out the third group first?

Along a similar line of reasoning I have a few more questions:

Is Nitrogen the most potentially spin-polarizable element (that is, having the most valence elections in the same orbital) with its `1s2 2s2 2p3` configuration?

Do the outermost `s1` and `s2` electrons block an outside observer from measuring the larger inner group orbitals for elements heavier than Nitrogen (for instance, would Chromium's `4s1` electron or Manganese's `4s2` electrons prevent you from detecting the spin of the `3d5` electrons in either case?)

Is there any relation in discernible properties between an `s`, `p`, `d`, `f`, `g` orbital electron with the same spin (in other words, say every partially-filled shell is spin polarized, would you be able to detect an all-up or all-down configuration of `3d5 4s1` in an atom of Manganese vs an atom of Manganese with either an up spin on `3d5` and down spin on `4s1` or a down spin on `3d5` and an up spin on `4s1`?)

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11042/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30229/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/255465/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do electrons not fully fill up all the orbitals sequentially?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/255465/)

Comment: I think you will find that denizens of the chemistry.stackexchange.com site will be better able to answer your questions. Also - please consider splitting your query so there is "one question per question"...

Comment: @Floris I tried the chemistry stack exchange first but they down-voted it to the point I couldn't split it into separate questions because I can no longer ask questions there.  I figured it might just be that they don't deal with the quantum stuff as often (it was [only in 2014 apparently](https://phys.org/news/2014-09-para-ortho.html) that chemists seem to have accepted quantum electron configurations playing a role in reactions.)

Comment: @Qmechanic It doesn't appear those links answer this set of questions.  I would also strongly prefer anything which avoids the Aufbau principle completely since it is not an absolute, but a rule of thumb (I'm trying to understand the actual reasons behind this, not apply a rule to 95% of the problems I encounter in a chem class.)