# Why is order of electron orbital filling not completely sequential?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals

Orbitals fill in the following order, 1s, 2s, 2p, 3s, 3p, 4s, 3d, 4p, 5s, 4d, 5p, 6s, etc.  Its a nice pattern that many elements follow, but there are exceptions to.  For example:

V:  1s<sup>2</sup> ... 4s<sup>2</sup> 3d<sup>3</sup>
Cr: 1s<sup>2</sup> ... 4s<sup>1</sup> 3d<sup>5</sup>

And not: (which would seem to be breaking pattern)

Cr: 1s<sup>2</sup> ... 4s<sup>2</sup> 3d<sup>4</sup>

This can also be seen on other elements, where a higher shell 'steals' from one below it in a seemingly random order.  Is there a reason behind this, and if so,  even if complex, what pattern is there to it?

I am new to the world of the very small, new to chemistry.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This isn't random at all. The key factor here is the half-filling of the d shell, which offers additional stability that beats the energy difference to 4s. There are other ways this can happen, but you'll find that most exceptions are this and similar mechanisms. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle for more details and lists of exceptions.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11042/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30229/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103718/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order you show applies to the H-atom.  But electrons in larger atoms interact with each other as well as with the atomic nucleus.  This causes some of the order you cited to break down.

Comment: Indeed, and it is perhaps to be marveled at that the one-electron levels for H pretty much keep their identities in 40- or 50-electron (and many more!) atoms.