# Can Aufbau principle be derived/proved with a definite reason?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals, pauli-exclusion-principle

How is [Aufbau principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle) derived or proved?

on a note,
why does the energy of 3d subshell is More than that of 4s subshell,
instead

as 4s is greater in extent than 3d,4s should have greater energy!

though I have read the answers here

[Is Palladium an exception?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11042/2451)

[Could the Periodic Table have been done using group theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30229/2451)

[Aufbau principle in modern quantum theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103718/2451)

I cannot find a definite explaination or proof of the above theory(rule)

Comment: Wikipedia states that the Aufbau principle is an empirical rule with exceptions without a rigorous proof. Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11042/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30229/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103718/2451 and links therein.